# Printing Position and characters in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script that prints position + character per line. Only characters A,a,B or b are allowed. If I find  "A" or "a", the script ends. If I find "B" or "b", the script continues. The length of string have to be irrelevant.

Example:

typing "**BbBba"**, the script will inform to user all the position, one by one, and exit when appears "a", like this:

```
B - position 0
b - position 1
B - position 2
b - position 3
a - position 4 # done
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=
while true; do
    read -p "Enter only A or B: " input
    if [[ $input =~ ^[abAB]+$ ]]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Invalid input. Please try again."
    fi
done

array=`echo $input| fold -w1`
counter=0

for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo "$i - position $counter"
    counter=$[ $counter + 1  ]
    if [ $i == 'a' -o $i == 'A' ]; then
       break
    fi
done
```

This code will first check if the user input contains only `A, B, a` or `b` in the first `while` loop. The next part of the code will then convert the string into character array. Finally it will then print out the value as well as its position. The script will end if the character contains either `A` or `a`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you call your variable `array`? it's not an array at all. Why do you use the expansion `${array[@]}` since it's not an array?